# BitSet does not prints its content when setting high index on

Tags: java

in below code, bitSet content prints as empty, however if idx changed as 1000, then bitSet value gets printed as expected.

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();

int idx = 10000;
bitSet.set(idx);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < bitSet.length(); i++) {
    if(bitSet.get(i) == true) sb.append(1);
    else sb.append(0);
}

System.out.println(sb); //prints empty
System.out.println(bitSet.get(idx)); //prints true
```

why this difference? thanks

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/ivX50ol.png) with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.3.1. I seem to recall issues with very long lines when using Eclipse. Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Where are you printing it? Is it IDE's console? If yes what is your IDE?

Comment: Yes, I used eclipse. when i redirect to a file, now i can see BitSet's bits. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove `int idx = 10000;` from your code you've to remove also `bitSet.set(idx);` which implies that any bit is setted to true (you need at least one bit to be true in order to reach a size for the bitSet). The bitSet will get as much bits as greater the last true bit is. So, when the compiler gets to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bitSet.length(); i++) {
    if(bitSet.get(i) == true) sb.append(1);
    else sb.append(0);
 }
```

as you haven't set any bit as true, it will skip the for statement and when you try to print the `sb` variable, it's empty. Thus, you don't see any variable.

You'll have to always set a bit as true: `bitSet.set(x)` to get a size for the bitSize. Source for information is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

As a side note, change `bitSet.get(i) == true` for `bitSet.get(i)` it returns true or false by default so you don't have to check it.